# How to make a copy and remove all protected ranges from the copied sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

What I want to do is

Make a copy of the sheet and remove all protected ranges from copied sheet.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var timezone = "GMT-5"
var timeformat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timeformat);

var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).makeCopy(date + " " + ss.getName());

var editors = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).getEditors();
  for (var i = 0; i < editors.length;i++) {    
      file.addEditor(editors[i])    
  }

  var viewers = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).getViewers();

  for (var i = 0; i < viewers.length;i++) {    
      file.addViewer(viewers[i])
```

this is what I'm doing to make a copy of the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you already have the copying part done, with `file` being the handle of the copy. All that remains to do is to [open the file with SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#open(File)) and then use the methods of [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) class:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file); 
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  protections[i].remove();
}
```